# Using the count as a parameter in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, count, duplicates

I'm looking to try creating a stored procedure that will search for duplicate rows based on a certain number (i.e., if I wanna see an instance of 2 identical rows, use "having count(*)>2)

```
 select invoice.first_name, invoice.last_name, invoice.date_ordered,
 sum(total_cost) AS Total_Spent
 from invoice
 group by invoice.last_name
 having count(*)>2;
```

What I would like to create is the option for the person to specify the count whenever they call the procedure so they don't have to go into the procedure, edit the query, save, etc.

Is there a way to turn it into a parameter?

Comment: you want this clause  `having count(*) > 2` parameterize?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
set nocount on;
create proc dbo.test
   @nas int
as 
begin
select invoice.first_name, invoice.last_name, invoice.date_ordered,
 sum(total_cost) AS Total_Spent
 from invoice
 group by invoice.last_name
 having count(*)>@nas;
end

exec dbo.test @nas=2
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what do you mean by:

> the option for the person to specify the count

If you mean that you want to specify the number of identical records returned, then you could:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE YourProcedureName (@Count INT) AS
BEGIN
 select invoice.first_name, invoice.last_name, invoice.date_ordered,
 sum(total_cost) AS Total_Spent
 from invoice
 group by invoice.last_name
 having count(*)>@Count;
END
```

This will create an input parameter so that when the user runs the procedure they can specify that the number of identical rows will be greater than the `@Count` Parameter.

If you want the user to be able to count on a specific column(s), that becomes a bit more tricky.